# Tabbar Start navigate from First Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating tabbar application it contains 2 tab bars, each contains Navigation controller.  When I press the first tabbar and traverse three subsequent navigation. Now I am getting calling/ any interrupt since app going to background (iOS4).

My question is when the start the app by double click the home button, it starts with Third navigation page & I want to start in the firstViewcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to restart the app from scratch at every start up, simply add/change the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your `info.plist` file

Here's the relevant [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) in the documentation